# Can't connect Qt with database (SQLite)

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

```
pro:
QT       += core gui sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Game
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
```

---

```
mainwindow.cpp:

#include "QtSql"
#include "QSqlDatabase"
//#include "QtDebug"
//#include "QFileInfo"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{


mydb = new QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); <------- ERROR LINE
mydb->setDatabaseName("C:/sqllite2/bazadannyh.sqlite");

bool ok = mydb->open();

widget = new QWidget();
```

---

```
mainwindow.h: 

#include <QSqlDatabase>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

QString *s;


QSqlDatabase *mydb;
```

I declared mydb here, because otherwise i can't get access to it in my public slots. Is it OK?

---

```
main.cpp: 

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "QtGui"



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();


return a.exec();
}
```

Is the place i choose to declare DB is correct? Or should i change it?

ERROR: mainwindow.cpp:19: error: expected type-specifier
       mydb = new QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
       expected ';'

Help me! What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header:

```
public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

QString *s;


QSqlDatabase mydb;//not a pointer
```

.cpp

```
mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
mydb.setDatabaseName("C:/sqllite2/bazadannyh.sqlite");

bool ok = mydb.open();
```

Comment: mainwindow.cpp:20: error: cannot convert 'QSqlDatabase' to 'QSqlDatabase*' in assignment
     mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

Comment: @MedetKoilybay see my edit please, it should be clear how to solve this.